# Compress Files Only

Tags: file, compression

I would like to have a script that will compress all the files (using tar) in the "logs" directory (Sandbox/tmp/logs).  Not sure where I'm going wrong but it is compressing all the files, directory and the path.  Which I do not want.  I just want to compress ONLY the files in the "log" directories.  Any help would be appreciate.

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_FILES="/Sandbox/tmp/logs"

for file in ${LOG_FILES}/* ; do
   tar -cvzf "${file}.tar.gz" "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely clear on what you're asking, but I *think* your problem is that you're providing too much path information to tar.  Lets say you have the following files:

```
/Sandbox/tmp/logs/foo
/Sandbox/tmp/logs/bar
/Sandbox/tmp/logs/baz
```

What you have will basically run the following commands:

```
tar -cvzf "/Sandbox/tmp/logs/foo.tar.gz" "/Sandbox/tmp/logs/foo"
tar -cvzf "/Sandbox/tmp/logs/bar.tar.gz" "/Sandbox/tmp/logs/bar"
tar -cvzf "/Sandbox/tmp/logs/baz.tar.gz" "/Sandbox/tmp/logs/baz"
```

Note how all the paths are included; tar tries to maintain paths in the archive so that when you extract a tarball everything is reconstructed just how it was (e.g., if you want to compress `foo/bar.txt` and `baz.txt`, when you extract them you probably want `bar.txt` to be in the `foo` subdirectory).

The easiest way to get around this is to just get rid of the paths… changing directories to `/Sandbox/tmp/logs` outside the loop should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_FILES="/Sandbox/tmp/logs"

cd "${LOG_FILES}"

for file in * ; do
   tar -cvzf "${file}.tar.gz" "$file"
done
```

With that you'll end up with the following new files:

```
/Sandbox/tmp/logs/foo.tar.gz
/Sandbox/tmp/logs/bar.tar.gz
/Sandbox/tmp/logs/baz.tar.gz
```

However, you're now still in `/Sandbox/tmp/logs`, which *may* be a problem later in your script.  To get around this you can use a subshell:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_FILES="/Sandbox/tmp/logs"

(cd "${LOG_FILES}";
for file in * ; do
   tar -cvzf "${file}.tar.gz" "$file"
done)
```

Now, all that said, you really don't need to use **tar** to compress single files.  Instead, you can just use `gzip` directly; you'll save a few bytes, and `gzip` defaults to creating a file right next to the input, so you can get rid of the `cd` cruft:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_FILES="/Sandbox/tmp/logs"

for file in "${LOG_FILES}"/*; do
   gzip -k "$file"
done
```

Which will yield

```
/Sandbox/tmp/logs/foo.gz
/Sandbox/tmp/logs/bar.gz
/Sandbox/tmp/logs/baz.gz
```

And `gzip` will happily compress multiple inputs to multiple outputs, so if you want a one-liner you can just go with

```
gzip -k "${LOG_FILES}"/*
```

And, if you have GNU parallel installed, you could compress the files in parallel with something like

```
parallel gzip -k ::: /Sandbox/tmp/logs/*
```